# Define $L_2(\Omega)$ as the completion of $C_c(\Omega)$ in scalar product norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am reading Aubin's [Applied Functional Analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=6iyejYSgM3wC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false). In Chapter $6$, he defines $L_2(\Omega)$ as the completion of $C_c(\Omega)$ in the norm topology induced by the scalar product
\begin{align*}
  \|f\|^2 = \int_{\Omega} \langle f(x), f(x) \rangle dx,
\end{align*}
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ is an open set and $C_c(\Omega)$ denotes functions with compact support. He claims the space acquired by completion is indeed isomorphic to the $L_2$ space (with Lebesgue integral) without proof. I am wondering how this isomorphism is defined?

Comment: This is just a restatement of the standard fact that continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L_2$ (w.r..t Lebesgue measure).